# Wifi ubuntu 22.04 suddenly disappears after usage for sometime

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

Wifi suddenly disappears after some usage time in ubuntu 22.04, when restarted the device the wifi works fine and again after some continuous usage wifi suddenly disappears. Attaching screenshots for reference. I have tried installing drivers from [rtw88](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88) repository still doesn't work for me, the wifi suddenly doesn't show. Below is the Output of `lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 6c:24:08:ee:0d:c5
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-34-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fd504000-fd504fff memory:fd500000-fd503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 9c:2f:9d:90:30:bb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.2.0-34-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.219 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:70 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd400000-fd4fffff
```

Output when Wi-Fi disappears

```
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: enp2s0
version: 15
serial: 6c:24:08:ee:0d:c5
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-34-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory: fd504000-fd504fff memory:fd500000-fd503fff
```

Checked logs with these, found some logs fishy with the Network manager

```
sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
```

```
Oct 18 20:22:16 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697674936.0034] agent-manager: agent[b643854d02c1ffd4,:1.113/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7245] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7520] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7520] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7521] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed no lease
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7523] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7523] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7523] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed no lease
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7542] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7544] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 18 20:42:54 vamsi NetworkManager[636]: <info>  [1697676174.7611] radio killswitch /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2 disappeared
```

[Wifi screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH3QA.png)

[Wifi screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3cPK.png)

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.

Comment: @waltinator These are the logs which I found fishy. Don't know the exact reason why I'm getting these, I'll update the post.

Comment: Try editing your connection (Gear in top tight corner, Preferences, Network) to disable IPv6. Investigate why the node you're trying to connect to is providing DHCP service.